# Is showing $\text{Tr}\Omega U = \text{Tr} \Omega$ equivalent to showing $\text{Tr}\Omega = \text{Tr}(U^{\dagger} \Omega U)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics

On pg. 30 of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* (by Shankar), we are asked:

> Show that the trace of an operator is unaffected by a unitary change of basis $|i \rangle \rightarrow U |i\rangle$. [Equivalently, show $\text{Tr}\Omega = \text{Tr}(U^{\dagger} \Omega U)$].

I have already convinced myself that

$$
\text{Tr} \Omega = \text{Tr}(U^{\dagger} \Omega U)
$$

by using the fact that

$$
\text{Tr} ( \Omega \Lambda ) = \text{Tr} ( \Lambda \Omega )
$$

implies that

$$
\text{Tr} \Omega = \text{Tr}(\Omega (U U^{\dagger})) = \text{Tr}((\Omega U) U^{\dagger}) = \text{Tr}(U^{\dagger} (\Omega U)) = \text{Tr}(U^{\dagger} \Omega U)
$$

as desired.

**Question:** But why is showing this equivalent to showing that the trace of an operator is unaffected by a unitary change of basis $|i \rangle \rightarrow U | i \rangle$?  It seems to me this means that

$$
\text{Tr} \Omega = \text{Tr}(\Omega U)
$$

which is a distinct condition from showing that

$$
\text{Tr} \Omega = \text{Tr}(U^{\dagger} \Omega U)
$$

Comment: You need to change basis in the domain *and* the range.

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean?

Comment: $\Omega$ maps from some space into the same space presumably?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I believe so.

Comment: So if you change the basis in the domain you must make the same change in the range in order for the new representation to make sense.

Comment: @copper.hat How does that correspond to $U^\dagger \Omega U$?  I'm assuming $\Omega U$ somehow corresponds to changing the domain while $U^\dagger \Omega$ corresponds to changing the range? Or vice versa?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are used to, but you can write $\langle x | \Omega | x \rangle = \langle x | U \ U^*\Omega U \ u^*| x \rangle $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a "change of basis" means in this context. In short: as copper.hat says, you need to change the basis in the domain *and* in the range.

The operator $\Omega$ of interest is represented by a matrix whose entries are $\omega_{ij}$. This means that
$$
\Omega |j \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_{ij} |i \rangle.
$$
In other words, the $j$th column of the matrix encodes the destination of the $j$th basis vector.  Correspondingly, if $M$ is the matrix of $\Omega$ relative to the new basis $U |1 \rangle,\dots U|n\rangle$ and has entries $m_{ij}$, then we should have
$$
\Omega (U |j \rangle) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij} (U |i \rangle).
$$
We can relate this expression to the original as follows: if we multiply both sides by $U^\dagger$, then we have
$$
U^\dagger \Omega (U |j \rangle) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij} U^\dagger U|i \rangle \implies\\
(U^\dagger \Omega U) |j \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij} |i \rangle.
$$
In other words, saying that $M$ is the matrix of the operator $\Omega$ relative to the new basis $\{U |i \rangle\}$ is the same as saying that $M$ is the is the matrix of the operator $U^\dagger \Omega U$ relative to the original basis $\{|i \rangle\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In an orthonormal basis, an operator $\Omega=\sum_{ij}\Omega_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|$ has trace $\sum_i\Omega_{ii}=\sum_i\langle i|\Omega|i\rangle$, which becomes transformed to $\sum_i\langle i|U^\dagger\Omega U|i\rangle$.

Comment: By the notation $\Omega = \sum_{ij} \Omega_{ij} | i \rangle \langle j |$, do you mean that each $\Omega_{ij} =  \Omega | i \rangle \langle j | = \langle j | \Omega | i \rangle$?

Comment: @user1770201 Actually, $\Omega_{ij}=\color{blue}{\langle i|\Omega|j\rangle}\ne\color{red}{\Omega|i\rangle\langle j|}$; the blue (red) expression is an inner (outer) product.